# OutOfBounds Exception when creating a PolygonShape using jbox2d

Tags: java, jbox2d

So here's the deal, i'm parsing a file that contains the vertices for a polygon, that i want to create in box2d. I create a `new PolygonShape()` and then call `.set()` giving it a defined array of `Vec`, and that defined array's .length property. I expected this to work, since the documentation for jbox2d says this method takes a Vec array, and the count of Vec objects in that array. However, it errors out, and it seems to be unrelated to my code. The error i get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.PolygonShape.set(PolygonShape.java:174)
```

and, upon looking at that line in the [jbox2d svn repository](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/trunk/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/collision/shapes/PolygonShape.java), i still cannot figure out the issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looking at line 174:     int[] hull =
        (intPool != null)
            ? intPool.get(Settings.maxPolygonVertices)
            : new int[Settings.maxPolygonVertices]; 

It looks like the problem is that intPool is not null and its size is less than maxPolygonVertices. That intPool is null if called from public final void set(final Vec2[] vertices, final int count) - are you calling the public final void set(final Vec2[] verts, final int num, final Vec2Array vecPool,
      final IntArray intPool) version and if so what value is being sent in for intPool?

Comment: i don't believe i'm using that 2nd set method. I appear to be using the first. I'm doing the following `PolygonShape pshape = new PolygonShape(); pshape.set(vertices, vertices.length); b.createFixture(pshape, 0);` where `b` is a properly created (using `World.createBody(BodyDef)`) body. where vertices is a properly filled and sized `Vec[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to create a `PolygonShape` with more than 8 vertices. Box2D, and thus JBox2D, default to a maximum of 8 vertices per polygon. This is why you don't get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` until index 8 (0 based indexing means it's vertex #9).

You can change the maximum number of vertices by simply modifying  `org.jbox2d.common.Settings.maxPolygonVertices`.

However, if you take a look how [PolyShape](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/trunk/src/collision/PolyShape.java?r=2) utilizes this setting you'll see why changes can have a global performance impact.

In [this conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186744/box2d-max-polygon-vertices) *iforce2d* suggests you can increase the limit a little, if you need, but should consider alternatives before making big changes.